# Device isn't compatible with this version - LG P705

Tags: android, google-play, android-manifest

Firstly, i appreciate that there are several questions asked about this topic, but I'm looking for an answer as to why this device isn't able to download my app (its currently in Beta version)

here are the permissions from my Manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.Camera" />
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3"/>
```

And here is a screenshot showing the features of the phone:
[image: LG P705]

I believe the app should be available for download on this device as it has a camera, and has GPS, email etc - all the features my app uses. However, the person who owns the device isn't able to download the app from the pay store for beta testing.

Can anyone see what is going on with this, and what i need to do to fix it?

Comment: Everything in the manifest looks good... Did the person trying to download it correctly join the G+ group for your app?

Comment: @NathanWalters Yes they have - that was my first thought.

Comment: What SDK does that phone have?

Comment: @DroidChris its running 4.0.2

Comment: Has the phone user restricted access to the SD card?

Comment: @DroidChris Not that the owner is aware of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a solid answer but may help start you out in the right direction.

Here is the link for the device reviews indicating problems with SD cards.

[LG Optimus L7 Customer Reviews](http://reviews.lg.com/1214-en_au/MD05024327/reviews.htm?sort=submissionTime&dir=asc)

Answer (score 0):

Your manifest is filtered by device setting. So to allow all devices to receive your app add **"    android:required="false"** to **every** uses-feature permission:

```
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera"
    android:required="false" />

<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera.AUTOFOCUS"
    android:required="false" />
```

This allows device without camera to install.

Comment: But this shouldn't affect the particular device listed as it DOES have a camera

Comment: Of course, this allows more devices to install without affect camera functionality handled by your app. And remember to add it to all suspect uses-feature ...